# Addig a second samba server to windows domain

Tags: permissions, samba

I'm trying to add a second samba server (stand alone) to our windows domain, managed by a Samba server, but we've had some problems, we see the server and the shares, but cannot access the shares. We decided to start with  minimal configuration.

```
[global]
    netbios name = GINGER
    wins server = 192.168.0.2
    workgroup = DOMAIN1
    os level = 20
    security = share
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    preferred master = no
    domain master = no

[data]
comment = Data
path = /home/data
guest only = Yes
```

Again trying to access the share gives permissions error.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would start enabling verbose logging level; put this under [global] group:

```
log level = x
```

where 'x' is 2 or 3; it could be up to 10, but increase it with caution. (http://oreilly.com/catalog/samba/chapter/book/ch04_08.html)

Comment: Thanks, at the end I started from scratch using SUSE 11 (previouly was using RHEL5) and everything was smooth.